# Too many redirection error on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, error-handling

I am getting "Too many redirection error" on an HTML page. There is no .htaccess or web.config and page is plain html file. There are some javascripts but I use them on other static HTML files, they work fine. What can cause this?

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>::Enerji Yönetimi ::</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- Mobile specific metas
        ================================================== -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

        <!-- CSS
        ================================================== -->
        <link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/animates.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!--
        <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/style.less" type="text/css">
        <script src="js/less-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div class="menus">
                    <div class="top-btns">
                        <div class="btns">
                            <a href="#" class="downloadable"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="search"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="user"></a>
                            <a href="#" class="lang-tr">TR</a>
                            <a href="#" class="lang-en">EN</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="number"></span>
                    </div>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">HAKKIMDA</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>

            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- Header. -->

        <!-- Banner -->
        <section id="banner-section" class="gaz">
            <div class="container oneByOne1 clearfix slides" id="slider">

                <div class="banner">
                    <div class="oneByOne_item slide-number-1">
                        <h2 class="slide" style="top:60px; left:0px;">Farkı Sizde <br>!</h2>
                        <p class="slide" style="top:140px; left:0px;">- Suspendisse volutpat vestibulum risus nec vehicula.  <br>- Vestibulum vestibulum enim massa, a fermentum turpis ornare non. <br>- Donec malesuada tortor sit amet lacus mattis luctus.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="detail slide" style="top:240px; left:0px;">Detaylı Bilgi »</a>
                        <img src="images/banner/clock.png" align="aa" class="slide" style="top:30px; left:700px;" />
                    </div>



                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Banner. -->

        <!-- Content -->
        <section id="content-section">
            <div class="container clearfix">

                <div class="news-side">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h1>HABERLER</h1>
                        <a href="#" class="next" id="next"></a>
                        <a href="#" class="prev" id="prev"></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="new" id="foo">

                        <li>
                            <div class="haber">
                                <span class="date"><i></i>10 EKİM 2013</span>
                                <span class="desc">
                                <p>Mauris non turpis turpis. Vestibulum varius scelerisque diam, eget laoreet risus suscipit sed.
    </p>
                                <a href="#" class="cont"> <i></i> Devamını Oku</a>
                                <a href="#" class="all"> <i></i> Tüm Haberler</a>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <div class="haber">
                                <span class="date"><i></i>10 EKİM 2013</span>
                                <span class="desc">
                                <p>Mauris non turpis turpis. Vestibulum varius scelerisque diam, eget laoreet risus suscipit sed. <br>
    </p>
                                <a href="#" class="cont"> <i></i> Devamını Oku</a>
                                <a href="#" class="all"> <i></i> Tüm Haberler</a>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="manas-btns">
                    <a href="#" class="mobile"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="order-form"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="counter-system"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="google"></a> <a href="#" class="apple"></a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- Content. -->

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer id="footer">
            <div class="container clearfix">
                <div class="copyright">copyright © </div>
                <div class="social-links">
                    <a href="#" class="facebook"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="twitter"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="linkedin"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="googleplus"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="youtube"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        <!-- Footer. -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/onebyone.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jqtransform.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validationEngine-tr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-5.6.4-packed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //  News 
            $('#foo').carouFredSel({
                prev: '#prev',
                next: '#next',
                scroll : {
                    items           : 1,
                    duration        : 700,                        
                    pauseOnHover    : true
                },
                auto: false
            });


            // Banner
            $(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('.banner').oneByOne({
                    className: 'oneByOne1',
                    sliderClassName: 'oneByOne_item',
                    pauseByHover: false,
                    width: 1010, 
                    height: 400,
                    showButton: true,
                    enableDrag: false,
                    showArrow: false,
                    slideShow: false,
                    responsive: false,
                    autostart: false
                });

            });

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: Is your project hosted somewhere or is this happening on your localhost?

Comment: maybe you paste a html tag to refresh?

Comment: It is hosted on my VPS @Tomás